# Unable to get response body in mockMVC

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, spring-data-mongodb, spring-test, mockmvc

I am trying to write test cases for controller layer in Spring boot using mockMVC, the test case passes but I am unable to see anything in the response body section.

The controller function:

```
private IPatientService patientService;

public PatientController(IPatientService patientService){
    this.patientService = patientService;
}

@PostMapping (value = "/save")
public ResponseEntity<Patient> savePatient(@RequestBody Patient patient) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(patientService.savePatient(patient));
}
```

The test case :

```
@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc;

@Mock
IPatientService iPatientService;

@InjectMocks
PatientController patientController;

Patient patient = new Patient();

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(patientController).build();
    patient.setId(1L);
}
@Test
@Order(1)
void savePatient() throws Exception {
    when(iPatientService.savePatient(patient)).thenReturn(patient);
    // The commented lines have been written for testing purposes and all of the following are working
    // ResponseEntity<Patient> response = patientController.savePatient(patient);
    // assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());
    // assertEquals(patient.getId(), response.getBody().getId());
    // System.out.println(response.getBody()); // response body contains the patient

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonBody = mapper.writeValueAsString(patient);
    System.out.println(iPatientService.savePatient(patient).toString()); // prints json body containing the patient

    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/patient/save").content(jsonBody).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(print()); // Do print is not printing the patient in response body
}
```

The response contains nothing in the body

```
    MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Need some help with what's going on and how to proceed? I am not sure why there is nothing inside the body of response.

Comment: Your mock doesn't match. I suspectyou haven't implemented a proper equals/hashCode in your Patient. You go from Patient -> JSON -> Patient and thus `Patient.equals(Patient)` is false as it isn't the same, implement a proper equals/hashCode.

Comment: @malverndongeni But the Id is being set right? Shouldn't it just return a patient with atleast the id?

Comment: Oh my bad I didn't see that part, so definitely there is a need for hashCode() and toString()

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to not implementing a correct `equals` and `hashCode` in your entities and in this case the `Patient`. How to implement a those methods properly can be found [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

In short add this to your `Patient` class.

```java
@Entity
public Patient {

  public int hashCode() {
    return getClass().hashCode();
  }

  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) return true;
 
    if (if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) {
            return false;
    }
    Patient other = (Patient) obj;
 
    return id != null &&
               id.equals(other.getId());
  }
}
```

With this your mocking, `when(iPatientService.savePatient(patient)).thenReturn(patient);`, will now match the patient.

Bonus tip use `@WebMvcTest` and `@MockBean` instead of what you are doing now.

```java
@WebMvcTest(PatientController.class)
public class PatientControllerTests {
@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
IPatientService iPatientService;

@Autowired
PatientController patientController;

Patient patient = new Patient();

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    patient.setId(1L);
}

@Test
@Order(1)
void savePatient() throws Exception {
    when(iPatientService.savePatient(patient)).thenReturn(patient);
patient

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonBody = mapper.writeValueAsString(patient);
 
 
 
 this.mockMvc.perform(post("/patient/save").content(jsonBody).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(print());
}
}
```

Comment: The id is actually a part of base domain class that is a private field of it's own. Patient class extends that base domain class but because of Id being private, I can't really add the hashcode implementation to patient class. Any suggestions? Also, I am not really sure why does the test case pass in this case?

Comment: Because the mocking now matches (it uses the `equals``). You can also put the equals/hashCode in the super class, you have to be a bit smarter in the `equals` to check the type.

Comment: I tried by implementing hashcode in Patient by changing the private id in base domain class to protected and it worked. I am receiving the response body. Any suggestions on how to do that without changing the access modifier of id private data members cant be inherited anyways. Is there a way I can add it in Base domain class? In my case the base class is a generic class that looks like BaseClass<T, ID>

Comment: The `hashCode` doesn't use the `id` so that can be in the base class. The `equals` as well you just need to be smarter in the checking of the type. Just modified the answer to have a more generic `equals` method, both you can place in your base class.

Comment: So, you're trying to say without the implementation of `hashcode/equals` after `when(iPatientService.savePatient(patient)).thenReturn(patient);` if i try to do `assertEquals(patient, iPatientService.savePatient(patient));`  it would be false assertion right? Also, i am still not sure about why my test case had passed without writing the `hashcode/equals`? I am a bit confused about the significance of it. Testing the Apis through Postman worked just fine. But writing the test cases resulted in this.

Comment: No the assertion here would be true as you aren't going through Patient -> JSON -> Patient. It worked with postman as then there is no mock and the mocking fails due to a missing equals/hashCOde (which you should always properly implement for JPA btw!)

Comment: So the mock fail you're talking about in the `Patient -> JSON -> Patient` are not equal because the mocked controller is unable to see them as equal objects without the `equal/hashcode` right (the middle `JSON` being the reason)? Also, the issue only came after I wrote the test cases. So is not writing `equals/hashCode` would have created an issue that I haven't seen yet? Api testing in Postman seemed to work fine without the implementation.